# Visual Studio listbox text is too long

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I'm making an application for a friend of mine. This app contains a winforms listbox. The listbox contains tweets. Everything works fine but the problem is the length of the tweets. When a tweet is too long, the listbox cuts parts away. Example:

tweetListBox:

Thow tweeted: jalskjdkljasdljlasjkdlasjdlkjaslkjaskljdlasjkd...

It adds dots when the text is too long. I can't resize the listbox because then it's too big. Is there a way to make the text that's bigger then 100 pixels split into different lines?

Comment: What framework do you use? `WinForms` or `WPF`?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is this a WPF Listbox? Winforms? Html?

Comment: I use the WinForms framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there anyway to make ListBox items to word wrap if string width is higher than ListBox width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/are-there-anyway-to-make-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-string-width-is-higher-th)

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532368/multi-line-list-items-on-winforms-listbox-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the selection capabilities of a ListBox, you could switch to a multi line line text box. Use a regular text box and set the multi line property = true. Stretch the control to the appropriate size to match that of the ListBox. Add a new tweet using :

```
multiLineTweetBox.Append(newTweet + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: There's one problem with this solution. Because I append the textbox, it scrolls to the bottom. I want to make the textbox scroll position to stay at the top, or to go to the top after the tweets have loaded in. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Thow You can add Text by using `multiLineTweetBox.Text += newTweet + Environment.NewLine`. This way, it should stay at the top.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Waka and ddrjca!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by just setting a property like WordWrap = true, it simply doesn't exists. A solution already has been given on StackOverflow here:

[Winforms DotNet ListBox items to word wrap if content string width is bigger than ListBox width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/are-there-anyway-to-make-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-string-width-is-higher-th)

Comment: This method makes the listbox drawmode to ownerDrawVariable. If I do that it doesn't draw anything anymore. Is there a better method?

Comment: According to the responses on the provided solution, it should work. You could create your own user control.